# How does production inputs price volatility affect production price?

Tags: reference-request, price-theory

Suppose a price ($P$) of a final good is a function of the costs, such as labor cost, costs for commodities, markup, i.e.:

$$P=f(\mu,LC,Com,...),$$

where $\mu$ is the markup, $LC$ is the labor cost, $Com$ is the cost for commodity.

Are there any theories or empirical evidence on the relationship between volatility of $Com$ and $P$? In other words, if volatility of commodity prices change how it affects final good's price?